# Не отображается текст на сайте

Tags: css, шрифты

Некоторые клиенты жалуются, что у них якобы не отображается текст на сайте, один из них даже прислал скриншоты 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я проверял во всех браузерах, и со шрифтами должен быть порядок... В чем может быть проблема? Сайт Fastumgame.ru

Comment: Наверное проблема клиента. Так же в Windows 7 сталкивался с проблемой шрифтов в Хроме, но там он просто шрифты на пиксель больше рисовал, чем остальные системы.

Comment: Клиент говорит, что у него и дома и на работе и на разных браузерах одно и тоже... Как точно проверить ?

Comment: Так может у клиентов чего-то блокируется?

Comment: Может быть... Как это проверить?

Comment: Попросите клиента открыть консоль разработчика в браузере (обычно на клавише F12 висит). там можно увидеть и ошибки javascript и css, и в разделе сеть посмотреть как загружаются/не загружаются файлы.

Comment: Проблема со шрифтом `Loto`. Сейчас глянул, тоже нет текста. Отключил `font-family` - появился.

Comment: А какая именно проблема со шрифтом Loto не подскажете?